# Deselecting an optional radio button in a form that mixes radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: usability, forms, radio-buttons

#### The issue

I'm working on a form which currently has three radio buttons. Originally, we chose radio buttons as we only wanted a user to be able to select one option.

```
o Option 1 (Default selection)
o Option 2 (Has an accompanying textbox)
o Option 3
```

We have now have been told that we need to make changes to this form. Whereas before a user was only able to select a single option, the business now wants to allow a user to to be able to select up to two options.

Option 1 and Option 2 will remain as radio buttons, but Option 3 will become a checkbox. Users will now have the choice to select either Option 1 or Option 2, and also have the choice to select Option 3. Or, a user can just select Option 3, without having to select either Option 1 or Option 2. No option will be set as a default.

```
o Option 1
o Option 2 (Has an accompanying textbox)

-------------

[ ] Option 3
```

#### The problem

The issue I foresee with the updated design is that if a user accidentally selects Option 1 or Option 2 they will not be able to deselect it. This section is part of a larger form, so they can't just refresh the form.

I've spent all day trying to find an elegant solution that wont change this section radically, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to share what the use case is and what the options are? What the user is actually doing would be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Radio buttons, when properly used, include a non-selection. So you'd have

```
• None
o Option 1
o Option 2
```

This is the equivalent of a dropdown that has, for its first option, something like "Select One."

If you want de-selectable widgets, then use checkboxes. The dev team at my workplace has built a custom checkbox component that includes min and max values for the number of items selectable at once.

Comment: A radio group with a "non-selection" is not to be considered "proper", nor is a drop-down with an option of "select one" - as both situations put the user into an immediate error state. If "none" is an accepted value, great! If not, it should not be provided.

Comment: I think putting the user into an "immediate error state" is not as bad as preselecting something for the user and risk that he does not notice.

Comment: As I see it, that immediate error state is the same as providing a required text field that's initially blank.

Comment: According to gb1986, 'None' is an acceptable value.

Answer (score 2):

I miss a little bit of background about the need of mixing radio buttons and checkboxes in the same question, but I guess it may be the incompatibility between `Option 1` and `Option 2`, so my recommendation would be a custom checkbox module that will disable `Option 2` if `Option 1` is checked, and also will disable `Option 1` if `Option 2` is selected:

Default state:

```
[ ] Option 1

[ ] Option 2

[ ] Option 3
```

Option 1 selected:

```
[X] Option 1

    Option 2

[ ] Option 3
```

Option 2 selected:

```
    Option 1 (disabled)

[X] Option 2

[ ] Option 3
```

Option 3 selected:

```
[ ] Option 1

[ ] Option 2

[X] Option 3
```

Of course, any other option will be compatible with Option 3:

```
[X] Option 1

    Option 2 (disabled)

[X] Option 3
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

o Only Option 3
o Option 1 without Option 3
o Option 1 with Option 3
o Option 2 without Option 3
o Option 2 with Option 3

[TextBox that is enabled only when option 2 is selected]